# Parameter Tuning in Microsoft R

Tags: xgboost, grid-search, gbm, microsoft-r

Is there any function to perform parameter tuning in Microsoft R? The equivalent function in R is ***train()***, which does a pretty extensive grid search and finds out the perfect parameters for the model using accuracy comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any RevoScaleR functionality for this. You can, however, use the 
R `train()` function in Microsoft R as well.